# Issue with Quartz and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

So I have a technical challenge I need help with.

A large scale project is using a Quartz scheduler to schedule a job to run every night at 9.
The Job that is scheduled, however needs to read values from property files, get some beans using auto-wiring etc.

When I used @Autowired and @Value annotations, I found the values to be null.

The issue is that Quartz creates JobDetail objects using `newJob()` outside the spring container. As can be seen in the below code.

```
JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("NightJob", "9-PM Job");
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(NightJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey)
                     .usingJobData("Job-Id", "1")
                     .build();
```

The `jobDetail` object which wraps `NightJob` thus cannot access property files or beans using spring.

Here is my `NightJob` class

```
public class NightJob implements Job{

    //@Value to read from property file; here
    //@Autowired to use some beans; here

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException{
    }
}
```

I scanned Stack Overflow and shortlisted several solutions. I also read through the comments and listed the top counter-comments.

> **Suggestion 1:** Get rid of Quartz and use Spring Batch due to its good integration    with Spring Boot
>
> **Counter argument 1:** Spring Batch is overkill for simple tasks. Use @Scheduled
>
> **Suggestion 2:** Use @Scheduled annotations and cron expressions provided by spring
>
> **Counter argument 2:** Your application will not be future ready if you remove Quartz. Complex scheduling may be required in the future
>
> **Suggestion 3 :** Use the spring interface ApplicationContextAware.
>
> **Counter argument 3:** Lots of additional code. Defeats the simple and easy concept of Spring boot

Is there a simpler way in Spring Boot to access property file values and autowire objects in a class that implements a Quartz job (In this situation , the `NightJob` class)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-quartz: *Jobs can define setters to inject data map properties. Regular beans can also be injected in a similar manner, as shown in the following example*

Comment: Hi, SamwellTarly, can you show me code example? I provided the setter methods, still got NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments, Spring supports bean injection into Quartz jobs by providing setter methods: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

Comment: Hi, I followed the doc above, but still got NullPointerException